# android:layout_weight unexpected behaviour?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:text="Button1"
        android:textSize="20dp" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button2"
        android:textSize="20dp" >
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:text="Button1"
        android:textSize="20dp" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button2"
        android:textSize="20dp" >
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

In code version 1
The height of button 1 is 5 times the button 2

In code version 2
the height of button 2 is 5 times the button 1

When android:layout_height="0dp" is replaced with android:layout_height="match_patent" the weights are reversed.
Can you explain this behavior and how android:layout_weights actually works and explain the reason in each case.

Answer (score 2):

Layout_weight is set to those components whose value would be specified as 0. This would mean that they don't have a height/width of their own and will take up a % of the screen as specified by the weight.